# Thermostat connection and NEST compatibility question

Tags: hvac, thermostat, nest, connectors

We have this thermostat. It's no longer allowing the temperature to be adjusted. It will control the furnace on/off, it just won't allow the temperature to be adjusted. Date & time are still able to be changed. The seasonal weather is about to change and so must the inside temperature.

We're considering replacing it with a Nest.
*(No opinions please. I've personally used a Nest for almost a decade and there's never been even 1 issue)*

When I answer the questions for compatibility at the Nest website, it says it's not compatible.

1. Does anyone here have experience using a Nest in a similar
   configuration?
2. If the Nest is not compatible, is there a similar
   thermostat that is? Remote (internet) access to the thermostat would
   be nice but isn't a deal breaker. If there are wiring differences,
   as there would be with a Nest (the Nest doesn't have all these
   connections), is there some place where I can find the proper
   connections?
3. This thermostat uses V & L connections. I haven't been
   able to identify what those do. Does anyone know?

I appreciate any assistance provided.

Thanks.

[image: A front view to show what it looks like, in case it helps anyone identify the model]
[image: The label on the inside identifies this as a White-Rodgers 1F95M-1295. Little to no information available on that model.]
[image: A slightly clearer image of the existing connections]

Comment: please disclose all the equipment you have, like dehumidifier, zone controller .. do you have 2 stage cooling, 2 stage heating

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler please, as well as its wiring diagram?

Comment: I don't have current access to the site but digging around identifies the following:

Furnace: Reem (manufactured for White-Rodgers) model number: RGFE
AC unit model number: AC: (-) ARL-JEZ16SEER
No zones - single thermostat.
By connections, it appears to be 2 stage cooling, single stage heating.

I've figured out what V & L are.
The V connection is PWM.
The L connection is an error return from the AC compressor.
There's no wiring diagram - hence my issues. I wish there was. I could probably figure it all out with one.